# My textlabel and detailtextLabel display the same text

Tags: json, swift, firebase, uilabel

[Iphone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ06M.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ06M.png

I'm trying to make it so that my textLabel and my detailTextLabel show two different things but for some reason they both say the same thing. There should be just one cell here with the top label displaying the number 2 and the bottom label displaying the ;slakdfj(random typing for now). Refer to the links above for screenshot.

here is the main vc:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage


class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableViewProducts: UITableView!

    var delegate: ListViewController?

    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    var postData = [productsList]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("0")
        loadProducts()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return postData.count

    }
    func loadProducts() {
        ref?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newSweets = [productsList]()

            for post in snapshot.children {
                let postObject = productsList(snapshot: post as! DataSnapshot)
                newSweets.append(postObject)
                print(self.postData)

            }
            self.postData = newSweets
            self.tableViewProducts.reloadData()
        }) { (error:Error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }

    //This places the text on the ViewControllerTableViewCell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let sweet = postData[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = sweet.id
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = sweet.p_name


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }

}
```

here is the structure:

import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

```
struct productsList {

    let id: String!
    let p_name: String!

    init(id: String, p_name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.p_name = p_name
    }

    init (snapshot:DataSnapshot) {
        id = snapshot.value as! String
        p_name = snapshot.value as! String

    }

}
```

Data Structure(is pretty basic for now):

```
[ {
  "id" : "2",
  "p_name" : ";slakdfj"
} ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you set the same value into id and p_name.
That's the reason.

```
init (snapshot:DataSnapshot) {
    id = snapshot.value as! String
    p_name = snapshot.value as! String
}
```

You need to change this code something like this:

```
init (snapshot:DataSnapshot) {
    var dict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    id = dict["id"] as! String
    p_name = dict["p_name"] as! String
}
```

Here you need to change "id" and "p_name" to fit your firebase database.

Comment: Ok now I'm getting a SIGBART error at var dict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

Comment: please share your database structure.

Comment: Updated with structure